# Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp i/o time out

Tags: kubernetes

When i run the kubectl version command , I get the following error message.

```
kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"9", GitVersion:"v1.9.0", GitCommit:"925c127ec6b946659ad0fd596fa959be43f0cc05", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-12-15T21:07:38Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 192.168.99.100:8443: i/o timeout
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Hi, can you validate that your client is requesting to correct api server with the following commad `kubectl config view`?

Comment: I guess so. I am a novice and learning K8s.Here's the output from config
`
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: REDACTED
    server: https://192.168.178.24:6443
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    user: kubernetes-admin
  name: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
current-context: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: kubernetes-admin
  user:
    client-certificate-data: REDACTED
    client-key-data: REDACTED`

Comment: hi you are having cluster on minikube or AKS ?

Comment: i am having a cluster on raspberry-pi . One master and two nodes

Comment: `kubectl config use-context kubernetes` will help you

Comment: Thanks. I had earlier installed minikube and just realized that I didn't uninstall properly. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: so its working now ? I think when you delete minikube it does not remove the data from kubeconfig.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can get relevant information about the client-server status by using the following command.

```
kubectl config view
```

Now you can update or set  k8s context accordingly with the following command.

```
kubectl config use-context CONTEXT-CHOSEN-FROM-PREVIOUS-COMMAND-OUTPUT
```

you can do further action on kubeconfig file. the following command will provide you with all necessary information.

```
kubectl config --help
```

Comment: error: no context exists with the name: "kubernetes"

Comment: You need to choose your own kubernetes context. *Did you check `kubectl config view ` for the context to use, as @Suresh wrote?*

Comment: or use kubectl get-contexts to check for exiting context name

Comment: @F34R `error: unknown command "get-contexts" for "kubectl"`

Comment: @DallasClark sorry without  -   get contexts

Answer (score 42):

You have to run first

```
minikube start
```

on your terminal. This will do following things for you:

```
 Restarting existing virtualbox VM for "minikube" ...
⌛  Waiting for SSH access ...
  "minikube" IP address is 192.168.99.100
  Configuring Docker as the container runtime ...
  Version of container runtime is 18.06.3-ce
⌛  Waiting for image downloads to complete ...
✨  Preparing Kubernetes environment ...
  Pulling images required by Kubernetes v1.14.1 ...
  Relaunching Kubernetes v1.14.1 using kubeadm ... 
⌛  Waiting for pods: apiserver proxy etcd scheduler controller dns
  Updating kube-proxy configuration ...
  Verifying component health ......
  kubectl is now configured to use "minikube"
  Done! Thank you for using minikube!
```

Comment: Or simply use `eval $(minikube docker-env)`, if the virtual machine was already started but the current shell wasn't linked to it.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. Resolved my error and able to run kubectl commands

Answer (score 17):

If you use minikube then you should run, `kubectl config use-context minikube`
If you use latest docker for desktop that comes with kubernetes then you should run, `kubectl config use-context docker-for-desktop`

Answer (score 16):

I had the same issue when I tried use kubrnetes installed with Docker. It turned out that it was not enbled by default. [image]

First I enabled kubrnetes in Docker options and then I changed context for `docker-for-desktop`

```
kubectl config get-contexts
kubectl config use-context docker-desktop
```

It solved the issue.

Comment: I had the same problem, than I removed minikube and enabled kubernetes on docker and everything became ok

Answer (score 14):

I was facing the same issue on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS.

The solution provided [here](https://techoverflow.net/2019/04/01/how-to-fix-kubectl-unable-to-connect-to-the-server-dial-tcp-443-i-o-timeout/) worked for me.

Just putting the same data here:

1. Get current cluster name and Zone:

   > `gcloud container clusters list`
2. Configure Kubernetes to use your current cluster:

   > `gcloud container clusters get-credentials [cluster name] --zone [zone]`

Hope it helps.

Comment: in gcloud, when connecting to a cluster through the UI, "gcloud container clusters get-credentials ... --zone ... --project .."  is the first command executed.  After that, the kubectl  works.

Comment: Even If the Cluster name and Zone is configured correctly as mentioned in O/P of clusters list . Please run the second command again. This happened to me when I created a new cluster.

Comment: This saved my butt. Here's some more details into why: if I do a `kubectl config view` I can see that my auth provider was expired (`expiry: "--yesterday--"`). Takewaway: on gcloud kube auth expiration does not surface in an intelligible manner.

Comment: also works with `--region [region]`

Answer (score 12):

This problem occurs because of minikube. Restart minikube will solve this problem.Run below command and it will work-

```
minikube stop
minikube delete
minikube start
```

Answer (score 4):

Was facing the same problem with accessing GKE master from Google Cloud Shell.

Then I followed [this GCloud doc](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters#cloud_shell) to solve it.

1. Open GCloud Shell
2. Get External IP of the current GCloud Shell with:

   `dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com`
3. Add this External IP into the "**Master authorized networks**" section of the GKE cluster - with a CIDR suffix of `/32`

After that, running `kubectl get nodes` from the GCloud Shell worked right away.

Comment: I tried it but it results in the error: "Invalid master authorized networks: network "35.233.xxx.xxx/32" is not a reserved network, which is required for private endpoints."

Answer (score 2):

I got similar problem when I run

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.11", GitCommit:"637c7e288581ee40ab4ca210618a89a555b6e7e9", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-11-26T14:38:32Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 192.168.99.100:8443: i/o timeout
```

And here's how I tried and finally worked.

I installed Docker Desktop on Mac (Version 2.0.0.3) firstly.
Then I installed the kubectl with command

```
$ brew install kubectl
.....
==> Pouring kubernetes-cli-1.16.0.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Could not symlink bin/kubectl
Target /usr/local/bin/kubectl
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/bin/kubectl'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite kubernetes-cli

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run kubernetes-cli

Possible conflicting files are:
/usr/local/bin/kubectl -> /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/kubectl
.....
```

That doesn't matter, we have already got the kubectl.
Then I install minikube with command

```
$ brew cask install minikube
...
==> Linking Binary 'minikube-darwin-amd64' to '/usr/local/bin/minikube'.
  minikube was successfully installed!
```

start minikube first time (VirtualBox not installed)

```
$ minikube start
  minikube v1.4.0 on Darwin 10.13.6
  Downloading VM boot image ...
    > minikube-v1.4.0.iso.sha256: 65 B / 65 B [--------------] 100.00% ? p/s 0s
    > minikube-v1.4.0.iso: 135.73 MiB / 135.73 MiB [-] 100.00% 7.75 MiB p/s 18s
  Creating virtualbox VM (CPUs=2, Memory=2000MB, Disk=20000MB) ...
  Retriable failure: create: precreate: VBoxManage not found. Make sure VirtualBox is installed and VBoxManage is in the path
...
  Unable to start VM
❌  Error: [VBOX_NOT_FOUND] create: precreate: VBoxManage not found. Make sure VirtualBox is installed and VBoxManage is in the path
  Suggestion: Install VirtualBox, or select an alternative value for --vm-driver
  Documentation: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/
⁉️   Related issues:
    ▪ https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/3784
```

Install VirtualBox, then start minikube second time (VirtualBox installed)

```
$ minikube start
  13:37:01.006849   35511 cache_images.go:79] CacheImage kubernetesui/dashboard:v2.0.0-beta4 -> /Users/kaka.go/.minikube/cache/images/kubernetesui/dashboard_v2.0.0-beta4 failed: read tcp 10.49.52.206:50350->104.18.125.25:443: read: operation timed out
  Preparing Kubernetes v1.16.0 on Docker 18.09.9 ...
E1002 13:37:33.632298   35511 start.go:706] Error caching images:  Caching images for kubeadm: caching images: caching image /Users/kaka.go/.minikube/cache/images/kubernetesui/dashboard_v2.0.0-beta4: read tcp 10.49.52.206:50350->104.18.125.25:443: read: operation timed out
❌  Unable to load cached images: loading cached images: loading image /Users/kaka.go/.minikube/cache/images/kubernetesui/dashboard_v2.0.0-beta4: stat /Users/kaka.go/.minikube/cache/images/kubernetesui/dashboard_v2.0.0-beta4: no such file or directoryminikube v1.4.0 on Darwin 10.13.6
  Creating virtualbox VM (CPUs=2, Memory=2000MB, Disk=20000MB) ...
E1002 
  Downloading kubeadm v1.16.0
  Downloading kubelet v1.16.0
  Pulling images ...
  Launching Kubernetes ... 

  Error starting cluster: timed out waiting to elevate kube-system RBAC privileges: Temporary Error: creating clusterrolebinding: Post https://192.168.99.100:8443/apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1/clusterrolebindings: dial tcp 192.168.99.100:8443: i/o timeout

  Sorry that minikube crashed. If this was unexpected, we would love to hear from you:
  https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/new/choose
❌  Problems detected in kube-addon-manager [b17d460ddbab]:
    error: no objects passeINFO:d  == Kuto apberneply
    error: no objectNsF Op:a == Kubernetssed tes ado appdon ely
```

start minikube 3rd time

```
$ minikube start
  minikube v1.4.0 on Darwin 10.13.6
  Tip: Use 'minikube start -p <name>' to create a new cluster, or 'minikube delete' to delete this one.
  Using the running virtualbox "minikube" VM ...
⌛  Waiting for the host to be provisioned ...
  Preparing Kubernetes v1.16.0 on Docker 18.09.9 ...
  Relaunching Kubernetes using kubeadm ...
```

**! still got stuck on Relaunching**

I enable Kubernetes config in Docker Preferences setting, restart my Mac and switch the Kubernetes context to **docker-for-desktop**.

Oh, the kubectl version works this time, but with the context docker-for-desktop

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.11", GitCommit:"637c7e288581ee40ab4ca210618a89a555b6e7e9", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-11-26T14:38:32Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.11", GitCommit:"637c7e288581ee40ab4ca210618a89a555b6e7e9", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-11-26T14:25:46Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

start minikube 4th time (after restart system maybe)

```
$ minikube start
  minikube v1.4.0 on Darwin 10.13.6
  Tip: Use 'minikube start -p <name>' to create a new cluster, or 'minikube delete' to delete this one.
  Starting existing virtualbox VM for "minikube" ...
⌛  Waiting for the host to be provisioned ...
  Preparing Kubernetes v1.16.0 on Docker 18.09.9 ...
  Relaunching Kubernetes using kubeadm ... 
⌛  Waiting for: apiserver proxy etcd scheduler controller dns
  Done! kubectl is now configured to use "minikube"
```

Finally, it works with minikube context...

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.11", GitCommit:"637c7e288581ee40ab4ca210618a89a555b6e7e9", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-11-26T14:38:32Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"16", GitVersion:"v1.16.0", GitCommit:"2bd9643cee5b3b3a5ecbd3af49d09018f0773c77", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-09-18T14:27:17Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Answer (score 0):

i checked the firewall port and it was closed, i opened it and it started working.

Comment: How do you do this?

Comment: as far as i can remember the firewallcmd disable worked for me that time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using azure and have recently changed your password try this:

```
az account clear
az login
```

After logging in successfully:

```
az aks get-credentials --name project_name --resource-group resource_group_name
```

Now when you run

```
kubectl get nodes
```

you should see something. Also, make sure you are using the correct kubectl context.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I use 2 virtual networks on my VM. The network which Kubernetes uses is always the one of the Default Gateway. However the communication network between my VMs was the other one.

You can force Kubernetes to use a different network by using the folowing flags:

```
sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16 --apiserver-cert-extra-sans=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx --apiserver-advertise-address=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Change the xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx with the commmunication IP address of your K8S master.

Answer (score 0):

I have two contexts and I got this error when I was in the incorrect one of the two so I switched the context and this error was resolved.

To see your current context: `kubectl config current-context`

To see the contexts you have: `kubectl config view`

To switch context: `kubectl config use-context context-cluster-name`

Answer (score 0):

Adding this here so it can help someone with a similar problem.

In our case, we had to configure our VPC network to export its custom routes for VPC peering “gke-jn7hiuenrg787hudf-77h7-peer” in project “” to the control plane's VPC network.

The control plane's VPC network is already configured to import custom routes. This provides a path for the control plane to send packets back to on-premise resources.

Answer (score 0):

Step-1: Run command to see all list of context:

```
kubectl config view
```

Step-2: Now switch your context where you want to work.

```
kubectl config use-context [context-name]
```

For example:

```
kubectl config use-context docker-desktop
```

Answer (score 0):

I face the same issue, it might be your ip was not added into authorize network list in the Kubernetes Cluster. Simply navigate to:

```
GCP console -> Kubernetes Engine -> Click into the Clusters you wish to interact with
```

In the target Cluster page look for:

```
Control plane authorized networks -> click pencil icon -> Add Authorized Network
```

Add your External Ip with a CIDR suffix of /32 (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/32).

One way to get your external IP on terminal / CMD:

```
curl -4 ifconfig.co
```

Answer (score 0):

**I will post the simplest solution:**

1. Go to terminal and type:
   `minikube status`
2. If it is stopped then type :
   `minikube start`

Done