# kubectl get componentstatus Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp xx.xxx.xx.x:xxx: i/o timeout

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl

While I'm trying to get the pods or node states, from Google Cloud Platform Cloud Shell, I'm facing this error? Can someone please help me? I can see the output of the "kubectl config view".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp i/o time out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49260135/unable-to-connect-to-the-server-dial-tcp-i-o-time-out)

Answer (score 0):

Posting this answer as community wiki for better visibility and the fact that the possible solution was posted in the comments:

> Does this answer your question? [Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp i/o time out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49260135/unable-to-connect-to-the-server-dial-tcp-i-o-time-out)

---

Adding to that:

Below command:

- `$ kubectl config view`

is used to show the configuration stored in your `./kube/config` file. The fact that you can see the output of this command doesn't mean you have correct cluster configured to use with `kubectl`.

---

From the perspective of `Google Cloud Platform` and `Cloud Shell`

There is an official documentation regarding troubleshooting issues with `GKE`:

- *[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: Docs: Troubleshooting](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting)*

There could be several reasons why you are getting following error:

- You are referencing wrong cluster in your `~/.kube/config` file.

  - `$ gcloud container clusters get-credentials CLUSTER_NAME --zone=ZONE` - you will need to run this command to fetch the correct configuration
  - You can also get above command from the `Kubernetes Engine` page (`Connect` button)
- You are referencing a cluster in your `~/.kube/config` file that was deleted
- You created [Private GKE cluster](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters)

For more information you can look in the `Cloud Console -> Kubernetes Engine -> CLUSTER_NAME`

You can also run:

- `$ gcloud container clusters list` - this command will show clusters and their state (status) they are in
- `$ gcloud container clusters describe CLUSTER_NAME --zone=ZONE` - this command will show you the configuration of the cluster

Comment: the kubectl commands were working fine but all the sudden they stopped worked for all the gke cluster...

Comment: Did they stop working for a single cluster, all of the clusters when you tried to change contexts? Have you experienced any network connectivity issues when you tried to connect to your clusters? Have you tried to use `Cloud Shell`?

Comment: the stoped working all the Custer and I was from Cloud shell

Comment: Have you implemented any firewall rules that could deny the access to your clusters?

Comment: can you please help me to find it @DawidKruk