# Connect to GKE via kubectl from local machine (mac)

Tags: macos, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl

Weirdly, I am unable to connect to GKE cluster from Local (Mac) via Kubectl, But I can connect from the Google cloud shell? I have fetch the K8s creds which I can see the kubeconfig file, still I am getting timeout. Any suggestions what might be wrong?

```
$ gcloud components install kubectl


Your current Cloud SDK version is: 367.0.0
Installing components from version: 367.0.0

┌─────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│     These components will be installed.     │
├────────────────────────┬─────────┬──────────┤
│          Name          │ Version │   Size   │
├────────────────────────┼─────────┼──────────┤
│ gke-gcloud-auth-plugin │   0.1.1 │  3.4 MiB │
│ kubectl                │  1.20.8 │ 89.0 MiB │
│ kubectl                │  1.20.8 │  < 1 MiB │
└────────────────────────┴─────────┴──────────┘

For the latest full release notes, please visit:
  https://cloud.google.com/sdk/release_notes

Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  Y

╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
╠═ Creating update staging area                             ═╣
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
╠═ Installing: gke-gcloud-auth-plugin                       ═╣
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
╠═ Installing: gke-gcloud-auth-plugin                       ═╣
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
╠═ Installing: kubectl                                      ═╣
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
╠═ Installing: kubectl                                      ═╣
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
╠═ Creating backup and activating new installation          ═╣
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝

Performing post processing steps...done.

Update done!


$ gcloud auth login
Your browser has been opened to visit:

    https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
You are now logged in as [atul@xxxxx.com].
Your current project is [test-dev-k8s].  You can change this setting by running:

$ gcloud container clusters get-credentials test-dev-k8s-cluster --region asia-south1 --project test-dev-k8s
Fetching cluster endpoint and auth data.
kubeconfig entry generated for test-dev-k8s-cluster.

$ kubectl get ns
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 34.93.111.251:443: i/o timeout
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After analyzing all the Cluster's configurations, I have found that *"Control plane authorized networks" was enabled* which was actually "Enable control plane authorized networks to block untrusted non-GCP source IPs from accessing the Kubernetes to control plane through HTTPS." and my local IP was obviously non-GCP IP.
Once, I have disabled it, I can connect from my local system.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to give a try to this complete cluster configuration access for [kubectl](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-access-for-kubectl), here you can find the steps needed to configure the kubectl in your kubernetes cluster.

If this does not work, here is a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49260135/unable-to-connect-to-the-server-dial-tcp-i-o-time-out) to some other workarounds for the same connectivity issue in the cluster.

Just as information, are you using minikube, docker or just GKE in your deployment?

Answer (score 0):

Login to your GCP account first using the Google Cloud SDK

```
gcloud auth login
```

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/login

Then goto GCP **Kubernetes Cluster** page, Select your cluster, Click on **Connect**.
Copy the **connection string** and paste it on your **Google Cloud SDK Command Line** on your local machine.
Then try to use the **kubectl** commands.

Comment: I've already done that, but no luck, still timeout.
I can run the `gcloud` commands and getting the output as well but not the kubectl one :(