# How can I solve i/o timeout when connecting to GKE?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

We have a functioning GKE cluster to which I wish to make changes but I am unable to connect to the cluster using kubectl in order to make those changes.
I have attempted to connect using the cloud shell in the GCP console:

```
jamie_thomson@cloudshell:~ (myproject)$ gcloud container clusters get-credentials clustername --region europe-west2 --project myproject
Fetching cluster endpoint and auth data.
kubeconfig entry generated for clustername.
jamie_thomson@cloudshell:~ (myproject)$ kubectl get pods
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp <IP redacted>:443: i/o timeout
```

The IP address mentioned in the error message is the same Ip address given in the GCP console as the cluster's external endpoint.

Given I am using cloud shell I would have thought I would be able to successfully establish a connection but alas I cannot. I would appreciate any advice on how I can solve this connectivity problem.

Answer (score 1):

This will happen when **kubectl** is unable to communicate with the cluster control plane.Verify the `context` where the cluster is set in order to resolve this issue.

To make sure the configuration file has the cluster `context` and the control plane's `external IP address`, navigate to `$HOME/.kube/config` **or** use the `kubectl config view` command.

If the cluster context is not set properly set the context using following command

`kubectl config set-context context-name --user=username`

For more detailed troubleshooting refer to this [**gcp document**](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting#kubectl-times-out)

Refer this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49260135/) link which helped in resolving the same error while using cloud shell and GKE.

Comment: Hi @jamiet Have you got time to check this answer? is it useful?